# Python script for copying a column

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find an answer.

Input:

```
a 3 4
b 1 4
c 8 3
d 3 8
```

Wanted output:

```
a a 3 4 
b b 1 4 
c c 8 3
d d 3 8
```

Note: the file .txt input has many rows in the first column.

Comment: Please clarify the input - are you reading columns of a .csv, are they array items or is each line a string and you just want to copy the first two characters to the beginning? Do you  just want to display the output, or manipulate it and/or write it back out to a file?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't ask for it, but would you want awk?  You could do:

```
awk '{$1=$1 OFS $1}1' Input
```

or the more obvious but less flexible:

```
awk '{print $1 $1 $2 $3}' Input
```

Comment: I was about to post an exact same answer!

Comment: as a python question?

Comment: personally, i think awk is a better choice for this case

Comment: The second example needs commas between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've read your results in an array, you want:

```
values = ["a",1,2,3]
values.insert(0,values[0])
```

This inserts the value of index 0 (in this case "a") at position 0, moving all the other contents of values to the right.

This will also work on strings, so if your results are read as a string you can do the following - please note that I am including the spaces after each digit and am doing it a bit differently:

```
values="a 1 2 3"
values = values[:2] + values
```

In this example we take the first two array members (`values[:2]` or `values[0:2]`) and adding the existing array values to the end.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("sample.csv") as inputs:
    for line in inputs:
        trimed_line = line.strip() 
        parts = trimed_line.split()
        print("{0} {1}".format(parts[0], trimed_line))


output:
a a 3 4
b b 1 4
c c 8 3
d d 3 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fin = open("text.txt")
content = fin.readlines()
fin.close()
for elem in content:
    print(elem[0],elem[0]+elem[1:-1])
```

**Output:**

```
a a 3 4
b b 1 4
c c 8 3
d d 3 8
```